# When I try to edit a record which use friendly_id, it gives me a no route match error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I am using friendly_id for my Product model. Here's my routes :

```
resources :products, only: :show

scope '/dash' do
   resources :products
end
```

Now when I go to the edit action, I used friendly ID to load the correct form. The edit form loads correctly. But when I submit it, it gives an error like this :

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/products/P011700714"
```

How can I fix this?

The form for tag :

```
<%= form_for( edit_product_path(@product) ) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps,

1. Remove `resources :products, only: :show` from your routes as that is what causing the problem, as you only need `show` action without the scope I would recommend you to add this line instead of `resources :products, only: :show`

   ```
   get '/products/:id', to: 'products#show'
   ```
2. Change your `form_for` tag to

   ```
   <%= form_for @product do |f| %>
   ```
3. Fetch the record using `slug`

   ```
   def edit
     @product = Product.where("slug=? or id=?", params[:id], params[:id]).first
     # your code
   end
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually I don't want the show action. I want to go to `update`

Comment: Isn't it possible to do it by keeping the rest of the product actions under /dash like in my routes file?

Comment: Yes you can do that, edit your question and add routes for the `dash` scope, that would help me answering the question

Comment: It's already there in the original question `scope '/dash' do
   resources :products
end`

Comment: No I asked you to add results of the `rake routes`, anyways no need to do that now as I have already edited my answer again. This should definitely solve your problem!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! That worked. Removing resources and adding only get for show action solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below [this link](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/frames) , i am sure you will get some useful

Please find my code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end
```

resources :users